# import compiled sass as string in vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, vuejs2

I'm trying to build a simple mail editor in vue (and vuex). Once everything is edited out of some input, i'd like to inline some scss files into the resulting html, using juice.
If i try to import one css using webpack raw-loader,

```
import css from '!raw-loader!./../assets/sass/test.css';
```

then i can pass the css value to juice

```
let result=juice.inlineContent(html,css)
```

and then injecting with v-html (*see below*) in one of my component to render the email.
Whitout using the raw-loader, the css will be applied to everything, beeing imported.

If i try to use the raw-loader with a scss file, it's not compiled - rightly - properly.

```
import css from '!raw-loader!./../assets/sass/main.scss';
```

I'm quite new to vue and webpack, so, is there something/somewhere i can dig in to understand a way to preprocess a scss file and then pass it as a string to vue, without applying it as style in vue?

I've also tried to scope some css to a component in which i use a v-html tag (and where the inlined html should go)

```
<template>
  <div v-html="render" />
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["render"]),
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

At first in the value (the getters) ther's no table, but when i add it to the component (with the editor) the style it's not rendered at all, as if the component is not re-rendered. That's the reason i decided to inline the css before injecting in the DOM, instead of doing it after some action - like a click on a button.

I've also tried using >>> but with no luck. I know this is not the main question, just a "side quest", but i'm just learning

Answer (score 0):

```
import css from '!raw-loader!sass-loader!./../assets/sass/main.scss';
```

It first compile the sass and then import it as a row string... easy peasy